# Using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end causing the filter to get called indefinetly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The snippet for the filter and template are as given. I am not able to figure it out why the console keeps coming for infinity number of times.

```
angular.module.filter('sumArrayAttrsFilter', function() {
    return function(sample, propName) {
        console.debug('cp$$$$$$$$$S1::', sample, '::', propName);
        return 99990;
    };
});
```

---

```
         <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, finData) in {'2014': [{'test': 4}, {'test2': 5}], '2015': [{'test': 4}, {'test2': 5}]} track by key">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {{key}}:: {{finData | sumArrayAttrsFilter:'test'}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat-end>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {{key}}:: {{finData | sumArrayAttrsFilter:'test2'}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me.Try this way.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('sumArrayAttrsFilter', function() {
return function(sample, propName) {
    console.debug('cp$$$$$$$$$S1::', sample, '::', propName);
    return 99990;
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, finData) in {'2014': [{'test': 4}, {'test2': 5}], '2015': [{'test': 4}, {'test2': 5}]} track by key">
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {{key}}:: {{finData | sumArrayAttrsFilter:'test'}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        {{key}}:: {{finData | sumArrayAttrsFilter:'test2'}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The reference to myApp module in

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
```

bootstraps the app using your module.

Here's the link [link] http://plnkr.co/edit/1TQsn2NujRB1ojuurVOd?p=preview

Comment: is this your expected output?

Comment: yes true it is working... may be I have bugs in some other part of the code.. Thanks a lot for the help.. :-)